# NetBeans theme by project type

Tags: netbeans, netbeans-8

Is it possible to use automatically use/switch to different themes when working with projects for a specific type?

I like Theme1 for PHP/HTML/CSS/JS/SQL but it looks terrible for Java so I choose Visual Studio Dark when working with a Java project.

Alternatively I could create a custom theme based off of Theme1 but then I'd have to set all of the values manually for Java for the new custom theme. If this is the case, is there a way to import just the Java part of the Visual Studio Dark theme?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look in the zip file of the theme. There you can see the themes per mimetype. Simply copy your favorite theme together and thus create a new theme.

Comment: What directory are the zip files located in on a Windows system?

Comment: At Tools|Options choose "Export...". The dialog check the mark at "Font&Colors" and provide a filename. This way you can export the current themes as zip.